# Add Action To Apple TV Remote Play/Pause Button

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, tvos

I have an AVAudioPlayer in my app and I am adding a function where the user can press the Play/Pause button on the remote to Play/Pause the AVAudioPlayer. I have this code in my App Delegate:

```
func initializePlayButtonRecognition() {
    addPlayButtonRecognizer(#selector(AppDelegate.handlePlayButton(_:)))
}

func addPlayButtonRecognizer(_ selector: Selector) {
    let playButtonRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:selector)
    playButtonRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue as Int)]
    self.window?.addGestureRecognizer(playButtonRecognizer)
}

func handlePlayButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    if audioPlayer.isPlaying {
        audioPlayer.pause() {
        } else {
            audioPlayer.play()
        }
    }
}
```

The AVAudioPlayer's name is an audio player. I have that stated in the code, but the App Delegate does not have a reference to the AVAudioPlayer from the PlayerViewController. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct. Just a missing detail that could explain why it does not work as expected... in tvOS, apart from setting `allowedPressTypes` it is also needed to define `allowedTouchTypes` as indirect:

```
playButtonRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already added that. The problem is that the App Delegate does not know what audioPlayer is "use of unresolved identifyer 'audioPlayer'