# Reference AVAudioPlayer in App Delegate (tvOS)

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer, appdelegate, tvos

I'm creating an app for tvOS that has an AVAudioPlayer. I want the Apple TV Remote's Play/Pause button to play/pause the AVAudioPlayer. Here's my code that I added in the App Delegate so far:

```
    func initializePlayButtonRecognition() {  
        addPlayButtonRecognizer(#selector(AppDelegate.handlePlayButton(_:)))  
    }  

    func addPlayButtonRecognizer(_ selector: Selector) {  
        let playButtonRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:selector)  
        playButtonRecognizer.allowedPressTypes = [NSNumber(value: UIPressType.playPause.rawValue as Int)]  
        self.window?.addGestureRecognizer(playButtonRecognizer)  
        playButtonRecognizer.allowedTouchTypes = [NSNumber(value: UITouchType.indirect.rawValue)]  
    }  


    func handlePlayButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {  
        if audioPlayer.isPlaying {  
            audioPlayer.pause() {  
            } else {  
                audioPlayer.play()  
            }  

    }  
}
```

The problems is that the App Delegate does not know anything about the AVAudioPlayer (audioPlayer). The audioPlayer is stated ion MusicViewController. How do I get the App Delegate to know what audioPlayer is? I'm getting this error - **use of unresolved identifier 'audioPlayer'**

Comment: duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428807/add-action-to-apple-tv-remote-play-pause-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add Action To Apple TV Remote Play/Pause Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428807/add-action-to-apple-tv-remote-play-pause-button)

Answer (score 0):

So did you actually create an instance of an AVAudioPlayer?

```
let player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
player.play()
```